# insufficient permissions for device

Tags: linux-mint, root, android

While using the command `adb root`

the output I obtained is

```
adb: unable to connect for root: insufficient permissions for device: verify udev rules.
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information.
```

Also tried to get help from this [Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360640/how-to-debug-adb-insufficient-permission-case) but the problem is same.

after this command `adb devices -l`
it gives the following output

```
List of devices attached
9f3a96d5               no permissions (verify udev rules); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] usb:1-1
```

and after giving command `lsusb`

it gives the output

```
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 091: ID 05c6:9091 Qualcomm, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c018 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

So, how can I get permissions to make changes(root,flashing custom roms, etc.)
I'm using `Linux Mint 19` in my PC and `Android 6.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with your user's permissions or udev rules under linux.

In order for `adb` to work properly, your user needs to be added to the following group:
`plugdev`

If that doesn't work I assume there's an error in your udev rules, or you need to add them:

`$ sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` - Put the following into the file:

```
# My android phone
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6",MODE="0660",GROUP="adbusers"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6",ATTR{idProduct}=="9091",SYMLINK+="android_adb"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6",ATTR{idProduct}=="9091",SYMLINK+="android_fastboot"
```

This is me assuming `Qualcomm, Inc.` is your phone. I might be wrong on that. Simply replace `05c6` with the vendor-id and `9091` with the product-id you get from `lsusb` using your phone's values.

After that run `$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` and re-connect the phone to the pc.